# Shift data of the form `Plot[g, {x, 0, 100},ImageSize->Large,....etc.]`

Tags: plotting, code-request

If I have the following:

`Show[data1, data2, data3,PlotRange -> {All, All}]`

where `data1`, `data2` and `data3` are of the form `Plot[g, {x, 0, 100},ImageSize->Large,....etc.]`

How can I shift the data that I see in `Show` for  `data1`, `data2` and `data3` without modifying the `g` of the data itself?

I was trying something like this, in order to shift the y axis of the plot stored in `data1` by 0.1, the plot stored in `data2` by 0.2 and the plot stored in `data3` by 0.3:

```
Show[data1/. {x_, y_} -> {x, y+0.1}, data2/. {x_, y_} -> {x, y+0.2}, data3/. {x_, y_} -> {x, y+0.1},PlotRange -> {All, All}]
```

I know that the easiest way is simply to use `/. {x_, y_} -> {x, y+0.1}` in the individual data but I was wondering if it is possible to do like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe `Translate`?:

```
p1 = p2 = p3 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]

Show[
 MapAt[Translate[#, {0, 0.1}] &, p1, 1],
 MapAt[Translate[#, {0, 0.2}] &, p2, 1],
 MapAt[Translate[#, {0, 0.3}] &, p3, 1],
 PlotRange -> All
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Michael, one question. I am trying the same for plots with `ListLinePlot` rather than `Plot` and it doesn't seem to work for  `ListLinePlot`. Is there something I can modify to make it work with  `ListLinePlot`?

Comment: @John The above works for me if I change the plot to `p1 = p2 = p3 = ListLinePlot[Sin[N@Range[100]/17]]`.  It does not work for some other one?

Comment: You are right, I was doing something incorrectly in my code. Also, is there any way to input rotation in your code? It only moves the curves up or down, correct?. Is there an easy modification to include rotation as well?. In other words, to have both translation and rotation.

Comment: Michael E2, I plotted the question here as well: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/238184/rotate-and-translate-data-of-the-form-plotg-x-0-100-imagesize-large-etc

Comment: There's `Rotate`. Just compose them.  `Rotate[Translate[#, {0, 0.2}], 5 Degree] &` or vice versa.  There's also `GeometricTransformation` for general affine transformations of graphics. `FindGeometricTransform` can be used to find the affine transformation that aligns points as well as possible.

Answer (score 1):

```
plot = Plot[2 x^2, {x, -2, 3}];
shifted = plot /. Line[l_List] :> {Red, Line[{#1, #2 + 3} & @@@ l]};
Show[{plot, shifted}]
```

[image]